# Clojure :: store configuration data in external file

Tags: clojure

At the beginning of my Clojure program I do a:

```
(def db-coords
    {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
     :subprotocol "postgresql"
     :subname (str "//" host ":" port "/" dbname) ;; host, port and dbname are defd above
     :user      "foo"
     :password  "bar"})
```

I would like to store these values in an external file (.clj or otherwise) on the classpath and load them from there. Clearly one way to do it would be using **java.util.Properties** but I suspect there is an idiomatic way in Clojure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using **[spit](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/spit)** and **[slurp](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/slurp)** with **[read-string](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/read-string)**.

Clojure has a built-in ability to serialize and deserialize its data structures.

To serialize to a file:

```
(spit "./coords.txt" db-coords)
```

To load the file back in as a string and deserialize:

```
(read-string (slurp "./coords.txt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

clj-config is a nice library which encapsulates the spit, read-string api

https://github.com/Raynes/clj-config

Answer (score 0):

I have created a library for handling env specific configuration regions via Clojure maps and JVM system properties:

https://github.com/bbbates/confijulate
This was a pattern that I found myself repeating over and over for every project.